# MSSQL Data type conversion

Tags: sql-server, oracle, stored-procedures, synchronization, type-conversion

I have a pair of databases (one mssql and one oracle), ran by different teams. Some data are now being synchronized regularily by a stored procedure in the mssql table. This stored procedure is calling a very large

```
MERGE [mssqltable].[Mytable] as s 
USING THEORACLETABLE.BLA as t 
ON t.[R_ID] = s.[R_ID]
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET [Field1] = s.[Field1], ..., [Brokenfield] = s.[BrokenField]
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
... another big statement
```

Field `Brokenfield` was a numeric one until today, and could take value N`ULL, 0, 1, .., 24`

Now, the oracle team introduced a breaking change today for some reason, changed the type of the column to string and now has values `NULL, "", "ALFA", "BRAVO"`... in the column. Of course, the sync got broken.

What is the easiest way to fix the sync here? I (Mysql team lead, frontend expert but not so in databases) would usually apply one of our database expert guys here, but all of them are now ill, and the fix must go online today....

I thought of a stored procedure like `CONVERT_BROKENFIELD_INT_TO_STRING` or so, based on some switch-case, which could be called in that merge statement, but not sure how to do that.

**Edit/Clarification:**
What I need is a way to make a chunk of SQL code (stored procedure), taking an input of "ALFA" and returning 1, "BRAVO" -> 2, etc. and which can be reused, to avoid writing huge ifs in more then one place.

Comment: You are going to need to change the datatype of that column in your sql server database. It will need to be a (n)varchar(SomeSize). It depends on the size of the column on the Oracle side to make sure it can hold all the data.

Comment: I would love to avoid that if possible. It will require massive refactoring of the software which is atop the mssql. I need to get a fix online today, and doing such a change in 100000 LOC software used by a huge company can be done only to fixed release dates with at least 3 month of testing.

Comment: Well you can't insert string like ALFA into a numeric column. You could wrap the column with a case expression and insert NULL when it is isn't a valid number. But what you are doing is taking data from a source that used to be a number and no longer is a number and inserting that value into a numeric column. The values MUST be numeric or it will fail.

Comment: I understand that they have to be numeric to insert. Is there a way to make a reusable chunk of SQL code which takes "ALFA" as a parameter and returns 1 as a number.

Comment: How are you supposed to "synchronize" data that is not even the same data type? If the change was made only on one side (the Oracle side), and the other side doesn't agree (for their needs, the column must continue to be a NUMBER column), there is nothing to "synchronize", since the two organizations don't agree to "synchronize" even the data type, to begin with.

Comment: Well, there is a 1-1 correlation in this case. 1-ALFA, 2-BRAVO, etc. Oracle team failed to inform my team until they did a release

Comment: Sounds to me like the Oracle team made a horrible decision. They essentially have an enumeration that now has the value in the database instead of the numerical reference. This is just a horrible decision and they should undo that "fix".

Comment: Which version of sql server are you using?

Comment: As @RichardHansell pointed out, isn't your `merge` example backwards? Which way is the data going? to sql server or to oracle?

Comment: I just cross-checked, data goes both ways....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can not simplify the logic for correct values the way @RichardHansell desribed, you can create a crosswalk table for `BrokenField` to the correct values. Then you can use a common table expression or subquery with a `left join` to that crosswalk to use in the `merge`.

```
create table dbo.BrokenField_Crosswalk (
    BrokenField varchar(32) not null primary key
  , CorrectedValue int
  );

insert into dbo.BrokenField_Crosswalk (BrokenField,CorrectedValue) values
  ('ALFA',  1)
, ('ALPHA', 1)
, ('BRAVO', 2)
...
go
```

And your code for the `merge` would look something like this:

```
;with cte as (
  select o.R_ID
    , o.Field1
    , BrokenField = cast(isnull(c.CorrectedValue,o.BrokenField) as int)
    ....
  from oracle_table.bla as o
    left join dbo.BrokenField_Crosswalk as c
)

merge into [mssqltable].[Mytable] t
  using cte as s
    on t.[R_ID] = s.[R_ID]
  when matched 
    then update set 
      [Field1] = s.[Field1]
      , ...
      , [Brokenfield] = s.[BrokenField]
  when not matched by target 
    then
```

Answer (score 0):

If they are using names with a letter at the start that goes in a sequence:

```
A = 1
B = 2
C = 3
etc.
```

Then you could do something like this:

```
MERGE [mssqltable].[Mytable] as s 
USING THEORACLETABLE.BLA as t 
ON t.[R_ID], 1)) - ASCII('A') + 1 = s.[R_ID]
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET [Field1] = s.[Field1], ..., [Brokenfield] = s.[BrokenField]
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
... another big statement
```

Edit: but actually I re-read your question and you are talking about [Brokenfield] being the problem column, so my solution wouldn't work.

I don't really understand now, as it seems as though the MERGE statement is updating the oracle table with numbers, so surely you need the mapping to work the other way, i.e. 1 -> ALFA, 2 -> BETA, etc.?